How to define CNN based layers to make it noise tolerant model?
I am trying to write a CNN model from scratch such that it is tolerant to the gaussian noise. I want to code a model such that given an original image and noised image there should be as much less as possible in the features of these two images.
`import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
class Net(nn.Module):
def init(self):
super(Net, self).init()
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25)
self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9216, 128)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
# x represents our data
def forward(self, x):
  # Pass data through conv1
  x = self.conv1(x)
  # Use the rectified-linear activation function over x
  x = F.relu(x)

  x = self.conv2(x)
  x = F.relu(x)

  # Run max pooling over x
  x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
  # Pass data through dropout1
  x = self.dropout1(x)
  # Flatten x with start_dim=1
  x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
  # Pass data through ``fc1``
  x = self.fc1(x)
  x = F.relu(x)
  x = self.dropout2(x)
  x = self.fc2(x)

  # Apply softmax to x
  output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
  return output

  random_data = torch.rand((1, 1, 28, 28))

  my_nn = Net()
  result = my_nn(random_data)
  print (result)`

I just want to extract features. How to modify the above code.
I have tried several libraries as mentioned above.
